# Perl multidimensional array search

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

i'm new to perl, and excuse me if my question confuses.

i have a multidimensional array which has 4 columns and many rows.

need to search if first element of each row is matches with a variable.

if matches , concatenate another variable in the 3rd column.
if NO match, push to the same array.

example :

getting 4 different variables from other loops/logic.

`$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`, `$var3`

and pushing them to a temp array.

```
push @local,$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4;
```

before pushing them main array i need to check, if var1 already exists in the column1 of  `@new array`. if exists, concatenate the third column of the same row.

if var1 not exists in column1 of `@new array`,  then push `@local2` to `@new`.

if anyone knows how I do this, please post how and it will be greatly appreciated.

thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what broke? Which documentation on "multidimentional arrays" did you read and on "searching in arrays" in Perl?

Comment: i have tried using for and if statements.. and that start checks each row, every time. there will be a row latter, but the if condition does not matches the earlier rows and keep adding them. actually, there is a true match latter. for eg. in row 15 there will be match. but all 14 rows, the condition become false, and add the entries.

Comment: Why not update your question with code you have? It will make it much easier to help you that way.

Comment: An example of input and desired output would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description was a bit vague, but this might do what you want. The part you need is between the 'CODE' tags.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Data::Dumper;

my @new;    # Array where data will be stored

# Define test arrays that in turn will populate the four input variables
my @testvariables = (
    [qw/a1 a2 a3 a4/],
    [qw/b1 b2 b3 b4/],
    [qw/v1 v2 v3 v4/],
    [qw/c1 c2 c3 c4/],
    [qw/v1 v2 vv3 v4/],
    [qw/d1 d2 d3 d4/],
    [qw/b1 b2 bb3 b4/],
    [qw/v1 v2 vvv3 v4/]
    );

# Test different values for input varibles
foreach my $row_ref (@testvariables) {           # Each round gives us a new ref to an array
    my ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = @{$row_ref};  # Update test variables
#-------------CODE--------------
    my $updated = undef;                            # Create/clear flag.
    foreach my $row_ref (@new) {                    # Loop though existing arrays in @new
        next unless ${$row_ref}[0] =~ /$var1/;     # Skip to next array in @new if $var1 does not match
        ${$row_ref}[2] .= "_$var3";               # $var1 matched as we got this far. Concat third element
        $updated = 1;                               # Flag that concat was performed
        last;                                      # No need to look for more matches in @new.
    }

    unless ($updated) {                         # If $var1 was not found in @new, append variables as array to @new.
        my @a = ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);      # Create array
        push (@new, \@a);                           # Add new array to 
    }
#-------------\CODE-------------
    print "-------------\n";
    print Dumper \@new; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how your array is organized. If it is an array of rows, then the map function is the tool you want. Write code that works for a single row and then use map to apply that to every row and collect the results.